# Reading bytes from URL, and converting binary to normal decimals. Obj-C

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have a file (with no extension) at a specified URL.

I want to be able to read every single individual byte from this file, and convert its binary coding to a normal human-readable decimal.

Example:

Read file from **URL -> load it into a buffer -> read byte number 20 (for example) ->** convert its value to a decimal / integer, that I can continue working on from there. (displaying on a label etc.)

Right now I can only manage to read the file when the file is local (with `NSFileHandle`), but since this file changes, and normally has to be read from an URL, there has to be a method loading it from an URL.

Thanks a lot.

//ifraaank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways for you to read resources from URL. Prior to iOS7, you can use NSURLConnection. Here is the example

```
    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://file.com/xxxx"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request 
             queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] 
             completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError 
                                 *connectionError) {
        if ( !connectionError ){
            //transfer the NSData into what you need
        }else{
            UIAlertView *alert = [UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error"....
        }
    }];
```

After iOS7, you can also use NSURLSession, here is the example

```
    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://file.com/xxx"];
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:
                          [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
    NSURLSessionTask  *task = [session downloadTaskWithURL:URL 
       completionHandler:^(NSURL *location, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        if ( !error){
            NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: location];
            //transfer the NSData into what you need
        }
    }];
    [task resume];
```

Hope this help.

Edit:
If you want to read the byte from NSData. You can perform as example

```
    Byte buffer[20];
    int bufferLength = 20;
    for ( int i= 0; i < [data length] ; i=i+20){
        memset(&buffer, 0, 20);
        //check the buffer length exceed the end of NSData
        bufferLength = (bufferLength >  [data length]-i)?(bufferLength = [data length]-i):bufferLength;
        [data getBytes:&buffer range:NSMakeRange(i, bufferLength)];
        //perform the buffer, it's a Byte[20]
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. How/where do I then specify which byte of the file I want to read? Let's say I want to read byte 20, with the iOS 7 example above.

Comment: I just add another buffer example for your reference.

Comment: It seems like this works. It loads the file into the buffer, but reading the byte doesn't seem to work. It spits out a number, which i know is not the correct. (I know the original value of the byte). I need to read byte number 20, 1 byte long only. It should read it in binary state, and convert, or at least spit out a normal number, like 89. Thanks again.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I managed to do it with subdataWithRange, and it spits it out with NSLog in a hex format. Now I just need to know how to convert that hex, to a label...

Answer (score 1):

To load remote file you need to look at `NSURLConnection`. You don't convert bytes to decimal, you just display them as decimal, or generate a string:

```
printf("%d", (int)theByte);
```

or

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (int)theByte];
```

One thing to watch as there is no `%d` equivalent for a byte, so you need to be careful you don't end up display a 16-bit int instead of an 8-bit int.